# SwiftUI ObservedObject not updating parent view

Tags: swift, swiftui, observableobject

I have 2 models: **Bag** and **Food**. A Bag contains 1 Food. The Food has a name.

I'm trying to bind the **Food.name** property with a TextField showed in the parent view (**BagView**) and another TextField showed in the child view (**FoodView**).

- When I edit the parent's text field the change is showed in bot the views.
- When I edit the child's text field the change is **not** showed in the parent view. Why?

Here is my sample code:

```
class Bag: ObservableObject {
    @Published var food: Food
    
    init(food: Food) {
        self.food = food
    }
}

class Food: ObservableObject {
    @Published var name: String
    
    init(name: String) {
        self.name = name
    }
}

struct BagView: View {
    @ObservedObject var bag: Bag
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            TextField("Placeholder 1", text: $bag.food.name)
            FoodView(food: bag.food)
        }
    }
}

struct FoodView: View {
    @ObservedObject var food: Food
    
    var body: some View {
        TextField("Placeholder 2", text: $food.name)
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To pass data between two views you need to use `Binding` for the `FoodView`.

```
struct BagView: View {
    @ObservedObject var bag: Bag

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            TextField("Placeholder 1", text: $bag.food.name)
            FoodView(food: $bag.food)
        }
    }
}

struct FoodView: View {
    @Binding var food: Food
    
    var body: some View {
        TextField("Placeholder 2", text: $food.name)
    }
}
```

Answering on your comment I recommend to add an additional view / wrapper to preview `Binding`.
[image]

P.s. By the way if you are going to use `Food` as a part of the `Bag` view model, you don't need to make it class with Published properties. Structure is enough.

```
struct Food {
    var name: String
}
```

Comment: Thanks. The only drawback I noticed by using struct instead class for Food is that the editor preview doesn't work fine for FoodView: for example if I place 2 TextField with $food.name they don't stay synchronized.

Comment: Probably you use a "constant" to preview the Binding. Try to implement a View Wrapper. I added code to the answer.